# raise KeyError(key) Python

Tags: python

I get this error when executing my code do you have an idea how to fix it? here is the image and the code of the first lines of my csv file, the file is too big to display it entirely. the code is complete. i try to display the points on a map with geoplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TNev.png)

```py
import geoplotlib
import csv
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('E:\Projet de Memoir sur les tics/humdataAL.csv')
geoplotlib.dot(data)
geoplotlib.show()
```

It returns the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nsama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\amara_project\venv\lib\site-packages\geoplotlib\__init__.py", line 32, in _runapp
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\nsama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\amara_project\venv\lib\site-packages\geoplotlib\core.py", line 364, in start
    self.proj.fit(BoundingBox.from_bboxes([l.bbox() for l in self.geoplotlib_config.layers]),
  File "C:\Users\nsama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\amara_project\venv\lib\site-packages\geoplotlib\core.py", line 364, in <listcomp>
    self.proj.fit(BoundingBox.from_bboxes([l.bbox() for l in self.geoplotlib_config.layers]),
  File "C:\Users\nsama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\amara_project\venv\lib\site-packages\geoplotlib\layers.py", line 159, in bbox
    return BoundingBox.from_points(lons=self.data['lon'], lats=self.data['lat'])
  File "C:\Users\nsama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\amara_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\nsama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\amara_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'lon'
```

Comment: Report the *full traceback*, not just the error. The traceback is everything that appears on your console log starting with `Traceback (most recent call last):` up to the error message that you showed us. Edit your question to include this. Do it even if it is very long and you don't understand why it might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask a question, try to show the full information. With a piece of code and the error, it is difficult to replicate your error and understand what is wrong.

Comment: hi, this is the complete code I displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV doesn't meet `geoplotlib` specifications. In particular, all rows must have columns named `lat` and `lon` in dataset.

Comment: the file is very very big was given to me for a project at the university how can I fix this in python

Comment: You'd have to post at least top few lines of the file to maybe let us know enough